# how to integrate and install node.js with codeigniter based web application running at online server?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter, socket.io

I just have deployed my Codeigniter based application to the online server.Now I have need to add instant messaging like functionality using socket.io.Which is possible by installing node.js.
So how can I install node.js with codeigniter at online server.

Comment: what does this have to do with codeigniter ?

Comment: Depending on the level of integration with the codeigniter project you need. You may consider using websocket with php directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can run node as any other OS process. There is a function in php ([exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)) which lets you run any shell command.

1) Install node on the server
2) Create a dir in your Code igniter project for your node scripts
3) Run the node scripts using the exec function, Something like this

```
$node_output = "";
$exit_status = 0;
exec("node /var/www/myCIproject/nodescripts/sendMessages.js param1 param2", $node_output, $exit_status);
if ($exit_status == 0){ // in bash/node 0 means no errors
    echo "Messages sent succescully!";
}
else{ 
    echo "there was an error sending the messages";
}
```

Something like this will run the node process synchronously (which means that the php code will resume only after the node process has ended) and then it's gonna put the output of the node script in the second argument as a string 
($node_output in the case) and the process status in the third one ($exit_status in our case)

Node scripts don't necessarily have to be inside the project, they can actually be anywhare in the server file system

Comment: I hope you have shell access to the server. Otherwise, good luck